# Use one_body_integrals to know which orbitals to freeze in ElectronicStructureProblem

Tags: programming, qiskit, vqe, chemistry

In exercise 5 of the this year's IBM Quantum Challenge, you need to use the `FreezeCoreTransformer` (along `two_qubit_reduction` and `z2symmetry_reduction`) to reduce the number of qubits to 4 and achieve a cost of 3. I managed to figure out that the optimal array to pass to the `remove_orbitals` parameter was `[3,4]`; however, I did this by experimenting with different arrays.

In the Qiskit slack, I saw that the one body integrals of the `QMolecule` are supposed to give you an insight on which orbitals to freeze. However, they didn't explain how to use it to figure this out.

The molecule and one body integrals I am working with is the following.

```
molecule = 'Li 0.0 0.0 0.0; H 0.0 0.0 1.5474'
driver = PySCFDriver(atom=molecule)
qmolecule = driver.run()
Matrix(np.round(qmolecule.one_body_integrals, 10))
```

$$
\displaystyle \left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}-4.7385372413 & 0.1075391382 & 0.1675852953 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.0302628413 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\0.1075391382 & -1.5131757719 & 0.0343466943 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.0680291694 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\0.1675852953 & 0.0343466943 & -1.1291622926 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.031432226 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.1407709359 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.1407709359 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\-0.0302628413 & -0.0680291694 & 0.031432226 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.9418187042 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -4.7385372413 & 0.1075391382 & 0.1675852953 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.0302628413\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1075391382 & -1.5131757719 & 0.0343466943 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.0680291694\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1675852953 & 0.0343466943 & -1.1291622926 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.031432226\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.1407709359 & 0.0 & 0.0\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.1407709359 & 0.0\\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.0302628413 & -0.0680291694 & 0.031432226 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.9418187042\end{array}\right]
$$

How am I supposed to interpret this matrix to know which orbitals to freeze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lab 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3B04KB0pDwE&t=667s) explains exactly how to do this for `LiH`

For more information, check out [Introduction to Quantum Computing and Quantum Hardware](https://qiskit.org/learn/intro-qc-qh/)

**Lecture 22**
[Quantum Chemistry I: Obtaining the Qubit Hamiltonian for H2 and LiH Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XEjrwWhr88)

**Lecture 23**
[Quantum Chemistry I: Obtaining the Qubit Hamiltonian for H2 and LiH Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWOfMWPKHDU)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Lookint at the lab lecture, I'm not sure I actually used the FreezeCoreTransformer correctly. Do you know if I'm doing it right? Or how should I use it taking into consideration the one body integral?

Comment: For context, I'm using the transformer as: `problem = ElectronicStructureProblem(driver, [FreezeCoreTransformer(remove_orbitals=[3,4])]) `.  I guess I'm missing the part in which the guy in the lab uses `freeze=[0,6]` in the video. However, my understanding is that this is done when `freeze_core=True` (the default); is this right?

Comment: Keep in mind that the lecturer uses `qiskit.chemistry` and not `qiskit_nature` - similar methods, slightly different behavior. Also, read the documentation on [`FreezeCoreTransformer`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/stubs/qiskit_nature.transformers.FreezeCoreTransformer.html): 1) when `freeze_core` is enabled, the core orbitals listed in the QMolecule are made inactive and removed; 2) **additionally**, unoccupied molecular orbitals can be removed via a list of indices passed to `remove_orbitals`.

Comment: True, I hadn't considered that part. Anyways, I think I've figured out how it works. Thanks for your help!